# TurboCARTO ramps do not work with CartoCSS user conditional filters

Tags: carto, cartocss, css

If you want to define manual class breaks with the `ramp()` function it seems you're out of luck; as far as I can tell this is not working as intended. For example, here I try to supply different colors for values that fall within user specified ranges

Code:

```
#layer{
           [dominant_origin = "Puerto-Rican"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#004c6d, #3d708f, #6996b3, #94bed9, #c1e7ff), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "South American"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#ff0000, #ff5d38, #ff8b67, #ffb297, #ffd8cb), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "Central American"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#00ff00, #6cfb53, #97f67e, #b7f0a3, #d1eac7), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "Dominican"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#ffff00, #fcf853, #f8f17b, #f1eb9d, #e9e4bd), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "Mexican"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#7f00ff, #a451ff, #c181ff, #daaeff, #efdbff), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "Other"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#000000, #363636, #6a6a6a, #a4a4a4, #e2e2e2), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
           [dominant_origin = "Cuban"]{
             polygon-fill: ramp([relative_dom], (#e6550d, #f17940, #f99a6b, #feba98, #ffd9c6), (.2, .4, .6, .8, 1), "<=");
           }
         }
```

if you console.log() the event on a metaDatachange you get this:

```
_buckets: Array(5)
0: {min: null, max: 0.2, value: "#004c6d"}
1: {min: 0.2, max: 0.4, value: "#3d708f"}
2: {min: 0.4, max: 0.6, value: "#6996b3"}
3: {min: 0.6, max: 0.8, value: "#94bed9"}
4: {min: 0.8, max: undefined, value: "#c1e7ff"}
```

If you `console.log()` `bucket.min` and `bucket.max` you'll get:

```
null
undefined
```

This is an issue for a few reasons. First you're getting nulls and undefined values for min and max in the first and last bins. Second, the class breaks are not explicit. Lastly, the last value supplied in the filter is ignored.

I know in a previous issue it was suggested to use the "<" mapping instead, but the result is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TurboCARTO, the CartoCSS preprocessor that works behind the scene everytime you run a `ramp`, does not support conditional styling. [This was reported 3 years ago](https://github.com/CartoDB/turbo-carto/issues/61). So do not expect to be fixed.

Comment: oh lovely, between CARTO's lackluster documentation and little silly things like this; I am beginning to see why it's not used very frequently.

Comment: The TurboCARTO project which is used by Builder UI and CARTO.js was kind of abandoned some months ago. It looks like CARTO tech team is focusing more on CARTOframes and integrations. You could also try CARTO VL is more powerful and dynamic than CartoCSS.

Comment: Whats the deal with CARTO VL? As I understand it, you can't use it iwth CARTO js. Does vector tiling lend itself to only specific use cases? Or can I pretty much do everything i do in CARTO js with VL ?

Comment: I would give it a try. As far as I know, you can do more things with VL than with JS.

Comment: have any potential guide/resource that compares the two? Can't find anything googling around